# Unity: Alternative for camera stacking/layering?

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

**Unity 2021.3.16f1/URP 12.1.8**

I've just started with Unity a few weeks ago and am still getting to grips with how everything works. So please don't assume I know everything there is to know about Unity. Treat me as a n00b.

I'm building a VR game for the Quest/Quest2. I have a scene with a keypad on a wall. When the payer "clicks" it, I want the scene to go dark, and a large version of the (3D) keypad to appear with which he can then interact (enter numbers). This keypad must always stay in the middle of his view.

What I did was create a canvas, and added a black plane with 50% transparency and the large version of the keypad. I've set up the canvas as follows:

[image: Canvas setup]

This works *somewhat*. It has two major disadvantages: 1) the keypad is receiving lighting from the scene while I want it to be fully lit all the time, and 2) the canvas and all its children clip through walls and objects while I always want it to be rendered in front of everything else (yes I know this will mess with your depth perception in VR, but I already have a solution for that).

So the next thing I tried, was *stacking cameras*. I created a second camera and set is as an overlay camera. I also set its *Culling Mask* to **UI**:

[image]

Additionally, I added the new camera to my Main Camera as a stacked camera. I changed the *Culling Mask* of the Main Camera to everything *but* UI:

[image]

This works they way I want it but at a cost: performance takes a **huge** hit. My frame rate actually halved. I read everywhere that this is a known problem for mobile devices (which the Quest really is).

Another solution I read about, is using RenderObjects. But I can't really find how to use this. I'm not even sure it really is a solution to what I'm trying to achieve.

So can anyone tell me how I should go about doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Haven't worked with VR, but the problem sounds like one that could be solve with a custom unlit shader that skips the z test.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up adding RenderObjects to the shader that skipped depth checking.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of lighting is the that you can setup the layer of your keyboard to something like "Keyboard"
And in Directional Light you can uncheck keyboard layer.

The solution of second problem is that you can change culling mask of camera on Run Time Like this:

~(1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Keyboard"))

renders everything except the transparent layer.

1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Keyboard")

renders only the transparent layer.

NOTE: You can set your own layer and check/uncheck what you want it is just a example

Comment: Thanks. For the lighting, I did just that.